# Как установить alglib

Tags: delphi

Как установить библиотеку alglib на delphi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) кинуть исходники alglib в папку с программой и добавть их в проект

2) создать новый пакет (File->new Package), добавить туда исходники alglib, собрать и установить. Не забыть подключить его в список runtime packages

Comment: и еще вопрос, в нем интерпретатор мат. выражений есть?